# Opening MySql database to search engines

Tags: mysql, indexing, search-engine

Most of my content on my web application gets stored in MySql database. I want to open this content for search engine to index it.

What is the best solution to do this.

Best could be either performance oriented or ease of implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Make webpages for all entries in the database and link to them." - I know if i could do this then problem would be solved but i want to know how do I do this in best possible manner.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot guys! But how do I go about doing this? besides using sitemap..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create a [sitemaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) xml file that could sit at example.com/sitemaps.xml and contain a dump of all blog posts, products, user profiles etc etc in a format google can understand (more so than a normal webpage).

You can also ping a url to tell google to come check your sitemap whenever you add or edit content.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about web based search engines (such as Google), then they index webpages.

Make webpages for all entries in the database and link to them.

Answer (score 0):

Like David said, a webpage should be available for each resource. Not only to force indexing, but also as a "landing page" to which the search result will then direct you. This can then of course be a redirect to another page.

The pages can be dynamic of course, but make sure that they are reference somewhere on your site so the spiders can reach them.